# Canceling a mocked function in Jest and getting the original behavior after a single call

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking, automated-tests

```
jest.mock("./MyService");
class MyService{
    async f1(args) {
        let out= await this.f2(args);
        ...
    }
}
...
// my test code:
MyService.f1.mockResolvedValueOnce([]);
await OtherService.f3(); // f1 is mocked and called in f3 and returns [] (everything is fine)
MyService.f1.mockRestore(); // trying to forget mocking f1 and getting the original behavior
MyService.f2.mockResolvedValueOnce([some data]); // I want original f1 to be called and mock the inner f2 but f1 is never called and I get undefined output from it
```

I'm trying to mock MyService's functions only occasionally and after using the mocked version, forget that mocking and get the original behavior of them. But when I do it for once and restore that mock, I get **undefined** for the output of the mocked function and it's actually never called.

Comment: How did you mock `MyService.f1`? Please provide minimal, complete code

Comment: @slideshowp2 I mocked it like jest.mock("./MyService")